# R: parsing data with a one-to-many relationship

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I am trying to parse into R a file which has data in this format:

```
Author:              Books:
Jane Austen          Sense and Sensibility 
Justin Bieber        NA
Shakespeare          The Taming of the Shrew | Much Ado About Nothing
```

It has a one to many structure. What I want to get is a data frame in a long format like this:

```
Author:         Books:
Jane Austen     Sense and Sensibility
Shakespeare     The Taming of the Shrew
Shakespeare     Much Ado About Nothing
```

This is more convenient if you want to get all the books by one author, or to find who wrote a specific book.

More generally, how would you convert a data frame in a (string, list of values) format to a (string1,value1); (string1, value2); (string2, value3) format? I know how to use strsplit, but I am less sure about the data frame manipulations here.

Bonus Points: I want something that works quickly (I have a large dataset in real life).

I was thinking of building an empty data frame of the right size (which is given by `sum(sapply(df$colWithListOfStrings,length)))`, and iterating with a for loop to fill it.

PS: We will assume here that a book has a single author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` package (very good tools from [Ananda Mahto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270695/ananda-mahto))

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(data, splitCols=2, sep = "|", direction = "long")[!is.na(Books)]
#                   Author                   Books
#1:            Jane Austen   Sense and Sensibility
#2:            Shakespeare The Taming of the Shrew
#3:            Shakespeare  Much Ado About Nothing
```

dput(data)

```
structure(list(Author = c("Jane Austen", "           Justin Bieber", 
                              "           Shakespeare"), Books = c("          Sense and Sensibility ", 
                                                                   "        NA", "          The Taming of the Shrew | Much Ado About Nothing"
                              )), .Names = c("Author", "Books"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                     -3L))
```

Comment: This is a great solution! Was able to easily show each of the one-to-many observations in contingency table form with `table(dataLong, useNA = "ifany")`